# How to obtain a full stack trace when test fails with an error?

Tags: lua, stack-trace, lua-busted

Especially when developing sort-of test driven, it would be really useful if busted output a full stack trace for tests failing with an error. I can't seem to find a busted option that would allow this.

Is there any way I can get a full stack trace instead of just a one-line error message?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Run `busted -v` as per [this issue](https://github.com/Olivine-Labs/busted/issues/399).